# Write R code of AR(2) model for a time serie data from `rsav` file

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I need to write R code to model a time serie data from `rsav` file. Here is detailed information about the question:

The file `“file.rsav”` (which can be loaded into R using `load(“file.rsav”)`) contains a time series (`“xx”`). The series is a `“demeaned”` monthly revenue stream (in millions of
dollars) for a company. There are `n = 96` observations.

The series has been `“demeaned”`; usually that would mean we subtract off $\bar{X}$ from every data point, but pretend for now we know the mean $miu$ exactly so we have subtracted off µ from every data point, so the new series is exactly (theoretically) mean `0`. (But thus its sample mean is not precisely `0`.)

We will consider possible `ARMA` models for the series $X_t$. We assume that the corresponding white noise is Gaussian (so `X_t` is Gaussian). We will consider first an `AR(2)` model. We assume we know the true model exactly: **$X_t = .1.34X_{t-1} - .48X_{t-2} + W_t, W_t \sim iid N(0, σ^2)$**.

I was asked to compute forecasts backcasts using model, up to `25` time steps in the future and into the past.

Write code to do the prediction by hand (i.e., not using the `predict()` function). Plot the data, forecast, and `95%` prediction intervals [assuming gaussianity] (all on one plot). (Note: you do not need to do a multiplicity correction for the prediction intervals.)

Code:

```
load('./file.rsav')
str(xx)
xx
```

Out:

```
Time-Series [1:96] from 1 to 8.92: 2.45 2.18 0.389 -1.44 -1.47 ...
          Jan         Feb         Mar         Apr         May         Jun         Jul
1  2.45017780  2.17955829  0.38874020 -1.43979552 -1.47049807 -2.25233354 -0.82580703
2  1.92378321  1.87944208  1.07382472  1.01933130  1.88660307 -0.31109156 -0.25732342
3  0.60732330  1.53185399  1.58614371  0.63922270  0.82728407  0.28910411 -1.18154941
4  0.41375543  1.96633332  1.97402973  4.16058136  5.15474250  5.71865844  3.93136013
5 -1.51228022 -3.03396294 -3.65446772 -4.69589618 -3.51276584 -2.97682246 -3.08655352
6  3.43027017  4.68909032  6.55598795  4.95816124  4.87626503  3.17103291  0.79093946
7 -0.62481997 -0.94469455 -2.13648402 -3.64364158 -2.07214317 -3.26793808 -3.38573375
8  0.67823828  1.09908274  0.93832242  0.08791237  1.77322327  2.01201710  3.70197246
          Aug         Sep         Oct         Nov         Dec
1  0.53048061  1.31994246  0.69306401  1.25916404  1.53363966
2 -0.47154459  0.52849630  0.90548093  0.71783457  0.86908457
3 -0.52525201 -0.40335058  0.73415310  0.58501633  0.29875228
4  2.50242432  1.69408297  0.96230124  0.53164036 -0.64480235
5 -1.60735865 -0.20500888 -0.44508903 -0.01443040  1.71087427
6 -0.09975821 -0.85972650 -0.41557374 -0.99876068  0.52620555
7 -2.25968715 -0.91700127 -0.49302872 -1.44275203 -0.66221559
8  4.62724761  4.17549847  3.43992950  3.15302462  4.17300576
```

I don't know too much about `rsav` extension file, could someone help me to solve this issue or give me some tips? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think with "backcast" the in sample fit for the last 25 observations is meant. To forecast from an `AR(2)` model you simply need the last 2 observations for the next step.

The model is: `x_t = ar1 * x_{t-1} + ar2 * x_{t-2} + error`

Now we just need to insert the estimated ar parameters and the observations for `x_{t-1}` and `x_{t-2}`. For the next step we need the forecast step and the last observation:

`x_{t+1} = ar1 * x_{t} + ar2 * x_{t-1} + error`

This is what we repeat 25 times. The error term is assumed to be normal distributed, so it is expected to be zero.

We do the same thing for the "backcast", the in sample fit, but here we only need the observations from the time series.

```
forecast<-numeric(25)
backcast<-numeric(25)

forecast[1]<-0.134*xx[length(xx)]+0.48*xx[length(xx)-1]
forecast[2]<-0.134*forecast[1]+0.48*xx[length(xx)]
for(i in 3:25)
{
forecast[i]<-0.134*forecast[i-1]+0.48*forecast[i-2]
}

for(i in 1:25)
{
backcast[i]<-0.134*xx[length(xx)-i-1]+0.48*xx[length(xx)-i-2]
}

ts.plot(xx)
```

Comment: Thank you. Can we use `a=c(0.134, -0.48); y=filter(xx, filter=a, method=’’recursive’’)`?